# How to be warned a many-to-many relation gonna be update?

Tags: php, symfony, events, doctrine

I want to do a specific treatment when a specific field is updated.

The obvious way is to do it with event preUpdate, and see what fields are updated. It works fine ... except for a many-to-many field. It triggers the event, but the ChangeSet is empty.

```
/**
 * @ORM\PreUpdate
*/
public function updateDate(PreUpdateEventArgs $event){
    $changeSet = $event->getEntityChangeSet();
    $res = "";
    foreach($changeSet as $key => $change){
        $line = $key." : ".$event->getOldValue($key)." || ".$event->getNewValue($key);
        $res .= $line;
    }
}
```

In $res all my fields are modified except for the many-to-many field.

Also, I'm trying to do it in a listener, but I can't find how to extract the fields which are updated from the entityManager.

Thank you.

More informations :

Relation from the update entity :

```
/**
* @var Status
*
* @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="projectsSupervisor", cascade={"persist"})
* @ORM\JoinTable(name="projects_supervisors")
*/
protected $supervisors;
```

From the other side :

```
/**
* @var Project
*
* @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Task", mappedBy="users")
*/
protected *tasks
```

Symfony version : 3.1.10

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to track changes made to an many-to-many-association. See [here](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/unitofwork-associations.html#important-concepts) :

> Changes made only to the inverse side of an association are ignored.
>   Make sure to update both sides of a bidirectional association (or at
>   least the owning side, from Doctrine’s point of view)

Additionally, ::getEntityChangeSet() is only useful for regular fields, not associations. For One-To-Many-Associations, you can use `$unitOfWork->getScheduledCollectionUpdates()` :

```
foreach ($uow->getScheduledCollectionUpdates() as $collectionUpdate) {
    /** @var $collectionUpdate \Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection */
    if ($collectionUpdate->getOwner() === $entity) {
        // This entity has an association mapping which contains updates.
        $collectionMapping = $collectionUpdate->getMapping();
        print_r($collectionMapping); // Investigate this further
    }
}
```

A practical example is viewable in my github repository "[DoctrineWatcher](https://github.com/dsentker/DoctrineWatcher)" which does [exactly the same](https://github.com/dsentker/DoctrineWatcher/blob/master/src/Watcher/EventListener/FlushListener.php#L196) (line 196+).